# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Tags: php

Need a hand..i am getting following error :

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\html_purple\design_your_own_card.php on line 213`

while line number 213 is :

```
<?php   <img id='image1' src='http://localhost/uploader/".$fulltarget."' width='280px' height='180px'/>   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `php` and `HTML`.
Try this..

```
<?php echo "<img id='image1' src='http://localhost/uploader/".$fulltarget."' width='280px' height='180px'/>"; ?>
```

OR just wrap your `php` variables in php tags..

```
<img id='image1' src='http://localhost/uploader/<?= $fulltarget ?>' width='280px' height='180px'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have html wrapped in PHP.

Try

```
echo "<html code>";
```

Or my personal favourite. Only wrap your variables in php tags.

```
<img id='image1' src='http://localhost/uploader/"<? echo $fulltarget; ?> width='280px' height='180px'/>
```

This will only work with short tags enabled in config.

Comment: Yes, the second is much better. It allows IDEs to understand the structure of the document, and so to offer auto-complete and syntax colouration correctly. This is not possible if HTML is hidden inside `echo` statements.

Comment: oops my bad. without syntax highlighting im hopeless lol.

Comment: Still wrong, see Ashwini's answer `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

You cant wrap html in php, you need to echo or print it out

```
<?php   print "<img id='image1' src='http://localhost/uploader/".$fulltarget."' width='280px' height='180px'/>";   ?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php   echo "<img id='image1' src='http://localhost/uploader/".$fulltarget."' width='280px' height='180px'/>";   ?>
```